# iOS app localization depends on user choice in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I'm pretty stuck with localization inside the app. What is idea:
You choose language inside the app, and depends on which language you choose it save value in `NSUserDefaults`. Because I didn't find material for this kind of localization, my idea is to make class that will have class method that return string depending on which language is saved in NSUserDefaults. Example:

```
+(NSString *) helloString
{
    NSString *hello = [NSString new];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
        hello = @"Hello";
    }

    else if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"] isEqualToString:@"es"]) {
        hello = @"Holla!";
    }

    return hello;
}
```

Is this legit way, is there any better solution?

Comment: There was a topic a while ago concerning how to set a localized language regardless of OS's language setting.

Comment: If you can give me link, cause I didn't find that...

Comment: stop stop stop... don't do that... ***I will leave programming if you do that...***

Comment: [this will help you](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=localization%20example%20in%20ios%20using%20.strings%20files)

Comment: @FahimParkar I know that this is not way, but time is running out, and I don't have idea how to do on other way.

Comment: @FahimParkar, I need solutions that is regardless of iOS language settings.

Comment: What you mean by `I need solutions that is regardless of iOS language settings` more details on exactly what you want...

Comment: I want to change app language from the app, I don't want to app be dependent on language from system settings. I have choice of three languages in app, and depending which language is chosen that translate will be shown in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I used `LocalizationSystem` class, which simulated changed language from system settings.